# modelling bespoke curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Trying to create something like image one. I've used a curve to make the basic shape. Question is what I should do with the overlapping geometry inside. Is it a manual fix (which would probably render this unfeasible given how many bends I need) or should I be treating this differently? I did look at self collisions with physics but this seems a little long winded and doesn't get an exact result. Or maybe it doesn't even need fixing?

As usual, still learning and just trying to find the right way to do things. Thanks all[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55302/rounded-caps-on-a-bezier-curve-pipe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285634/almost-like-that-old-pillow-emboss-in-photoshop

Comment: Appreciate the answer Duarte. I've had a play around doing this but can't see how this get's the result I want — I really want them squashed together at those corner points, so they are no longer round, they're almost flat at those sides where the curve meets each other

Comment: To be more specific, the first link is about rounding the ends, which I'm all good with, and the second link is more about creating a shape — but they're not influencing other curves. How I can make them squash together  at corners (and the right way of doing it) is more what I'm trying to do